# Convertir Fila a Columna SQL server query

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Buenos días,

Necesito transponer o cambiar el resultado de una tabla de la siguiente forma:

La estructura de la tabla es 5 columnas (descripcion usuarios, permiso1, permiso2, permiso3, permiso4 )

el campo descripcion es varchar(50) y los campos permiso1 al permiso4 es tipo Bit

La tabla tiene un listado de 10 usuarios.

```
Usuarios    1   2   3   4
USUARIO1    X   X   X   
USUARIO2    X       X   X

Permisos    USUARIO 1   USUARIO2
1             X             X
2             X 
3             X             X
4                           X
```

Gracias.

Comment: Cual es el diseño original de tu tabla? O sea, el nombre y sus campos? y muestra también las consultas que haz intentado

Comment: Bienvenido Hector, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], veas [ask] y por último como hacer un [mcve]. Con respecto a tu pregunta: 1) en preguntas con la etiqueta [sql] se suele pedir que se indique la estructura de las tablas como ya te undicó Adriana, 2) cualquier transposición de filas a columnas tiene límites muy acotados, cuantos usuarios como máximo planeas manejar?, por ejemplo un `SELECT` tiene un máximo de 4,096 columnas, que en tu caso representaría no más de 4095 usuarios.

Comment: Buenos días,

Necesito transponer o cambiar el resultado de una tabla de la siguiente forma:

La estructura de la tabla es 5 columnas (descripcion usuarios, permiso1, permiso2, permiso3, permiso4 )

el campo descripcion es varchar(50) y los campos permiso1 al permiso4 es tipo Bit

La tabla tiene un listado de 10 usuarios.

Usuarios    1   2   3   4
USUARIO1    X   X   X   
USUARIO2    X       X   X

Permisos    USUARIO 1   USUARIO2
1             X             X
2             X 
3             X             X
4                           X
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la función Pivot puedes hacer lo que deseas; fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
SELECT 'AverageCost' AS Cost_Sorted_By_Production_Days, 
[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM
(SELECT DaysToManufacture, StandardCost 
    FROM Production.Product) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
AVG(StandardCost)
FOR DaysToManufacture IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PivotTable;
```